# Swift/MSAL `is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level` errors on async call but not continuation block

Tags: swift, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I was trying to convert the MSAL functions in my Swift app to async from completion block, but I am running into `is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level` errors in xCode on the result from the async where I am not from the continuation block and don't understand why.

The code which worked was:

```
public func logIn(msalApplication: MSALPublicClientApplication, webViewParameters: MSALWebviewParameters) {
    let interactiveParameters = MSALInteractiveTokenParameters(
        scopes: [],
        webviewParameters: webViewParameters
    )

    msalApplication.acquireToken(
        with: interactiveParameters
    ) { result, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error)")
            return
        }

        guard let result = result else {
            preconditionFailure("expected result")
        }

        if !result.accessToken.isEmpty {
            bearerToken = result.accessToken
        }

        self.account = result.account
        self.account = result.account
        self.globalId = self.account?.getGlobalId()
        self.userName = self.account?.getUserName()
    }
}
```

I am getting two errors:

> getGlobalId' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

> getUserName' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

on this code:

```
public func logIn(msalApplication: MSALPublicClientApplication, webViewParameters: MSALWebviewParameters) async throws {
    let result = try await B2CAuthApi.logInAsync(msalApplication: msalApplication, webViewParameters: webViewParameters)

    guard let result = result else {
        preconditionFailure("expected result")
    }

    if !result.accessToken.isEmpty {
        self.accountToken = result.accessToken
    }

    self.accountTokenExpiration = result.expiresOn

    self.account = result.account
    self.isAuthenticated = true

    self.accountGlobalId = result.account.getGlobalId()
    self.accountUserName = result.account.getUserName()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect there is an async `getGlobalId()` internal overload, and the compiler is getting confused about which one you want to use, since this is now an async context and so async methods are available. Cmd-click on `getGlobalId()` and see what method it's resolving to.

That said, sometimes the compiler gets confused about invalid code and gives misleading diagnostics. Delete the calls to `get...` and see if you get a different error that is more enlightening.

Comment: My fault. Cmd-click helped me out. It turns out it's an extension I made for MSALAccount, which I needed to make public when I moved it back into a package.